# A kind of 0-1 law?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Suppose that P is a Borel subset of Baire $\times$ Baire, such that for every pair $x,x'$ of reals in the horizontal copy of Baire,

**if:** $x,x'$ are $E_0$-equivalent (that is, $x(n)=y(n)$ for all but finite $n$)

**then:** the vertical cross-sections $P_x$ and $P_{x'}$ coincide.

Does this imply that $P_x=P_{x'}$ for all $x,x'$ in Baire (or at least for all $x,x'$ in a set $X$ large in the sense of measure or category) ?

Comment: Isn't the equivalence relation $E_0\subset Baire\times Baire$ a counterexample to this problem?

Comment: I see ... it is